# WPF Animated GIF in RibbonButton

Tags: c#, wpf, gif, ribbon

So I'm having a RibbonControl with multiple tabs and underlying RibbonGroups/Buttons.
I would like to show a GIF as LargeImageSource on one of the buttons if the corresponding Backgroundworker is busy. So far it's working, I can see my DataTrigger shows the correct images depending on the state. The thing is, the image that should be shown as a GIF is only shown static (like a usual PNG). I've already downloaded [WPFAnimatedGif](https://github.com/XamlAnimatedGif/WpfAnimatedGif) but I can't get it working in the Binding.

That's the XAML code for it:

```
                    <RibbonButton x:Name="ImpFromForum" Label="From forum" FontSize="12" SmallImageSource="Icons/General/DownloadFile_64x.png" Click="ImpFromForum_Click">
                    <RibbonButton.Style>
                        <Style>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=frmMain, Path=ImportBusy}" Value="false">
                                    <Setter Property="RibbonButton.LargeImageSource" Value="Icons/General/Icon8_download_72px.png"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=frmMain, Path=ImportBusy}" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="RibbonButton.LargeImageSource" Value="Icons/General/Loading_Spiffy_64x64.gif"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </RibbonButton.Style>
                </RibbonButton>
```

The namespace "        xmlns:gif="http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com" is added and I can see it's working when using it in an image. But somehow I can't get it working in the Setter. Also I can exclude an issue with the Backgroundworker (occupying my UI thread) because the UI still reacts to commands. Someone an idea how to do that?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?